# Variables python

Tags: python, variables, variables-globales

Quiero crear una variable que será una lista, a la que llamo

```
lista_Madrid = ('cibeles', 'plaza_mayor')
```

Por otro lado tengo una variable que fijo en la ciudad que quiera

```
ciudad = "Madrid"
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿Puedo llamar esa variable según la que tenga fijada en ciudad, es decir, dentro una función por ejemplo llamar a la variable lista_ciudad y que llame a lista_Madrid.

Un saludo

Comment: es mejor que tengas una lista que contenga otras listas, tengo entendido que es posible

Comment: ¿porque no usas un diccionario con listas?
ciudad = { 'madrid': ['cibeles', 'plaza_mayor']}
la llamarias ciudad['madrid']

Comment: Puedes llamarlas y modificarlas dentro de una función, agregar la palabra reserva global delante de la variable deseada.
  `global ciudad`  `ciudad ="ESTO NO ES MADRID" `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***¿Puedo llamar esa variable según la que tenga fijada en ciudad?*** Respuesta rápida si y no.

Técnicamente se puede hacer algo así:

```
lista_Madrid = ['cibeles', 'plaza_mayor']
ciudad = "Madrid"

cmd = "{0} = {1}".format(ciudad,lista_Madrid)
exec(cmd)

print(Madrid)
['cibeles', 'plaza_mayor']
```

Usamos [`exec()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) para ejecutar un código arbitrario, en nuestro ejemplo, una asignación, si hiciéramos `print(cmd)` obtenemos lo siguiente: `Madrid = ['cibeles', 'plaza_mayor']` claramente una asignación de una lista a una variable `Madrid`. El tema es que hay múltiples razones para evitar hacer estas cosas, además de ser poco práctico (manejas variables que solo existen en tiempo de ejecución), siempre corres un riesgo potencial de una inyección de código malicioso.

La forma adecuada para manejar este tipo de situaciones es sin duda el uso de los [diccionarios](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) que son estructuras del tipo `clave: valor`, en tu ejemplo `ciudad` o `"Madrid"` sería la clave y `['cibeles', 'plaza_mayor']` el valor. Son además estructuras superoptimizadas, por lo que acceder a cada valor por clave es computacionalmente muy económico. Veamos un ejemplo:

```
Ciudades = dict()

lista_Madrid = ['cibeles', 'plaza_mayor']
ciudad = "Madrid"

# Usamos la variable ciudad como valor de la clave
Ciudades[ciudad] = lista_Madrid
```

Y por que no, puedes agregar otro caso más

```
# O también podemos usar una cadena literal como clave
Ciudades["Barcelona"] = ['Las Ramblas', 'Barrio Gótico', 'El Born']
```

Y si necesitas acceder al valor de cada "variable" o clave:

```
print(Ciudades["Madrid"])
['cibeles', 'plaza_mayor']

print(Ciudades["Barcelona"])
['Las Ramblas', 'Barrio Gótico', 'El Born']
```

Y la estructura completa es fácil de visualizar:

```
print(Ciudades)
{'Madrid': ['cibeles', 'plaza_mayor'], 'Barcelona': ['Las Ramblas', 'Barrio Gótico', 'El Born']}
```

Comment: Gracias a todos por la colaboración, lo estoy haciendo mediante diccionarios, creo que será los más efectivo.